# Looking for a method to replace sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.predict_proba(X) in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gmm

In `sklearn`, I can use `predict_proba(X)` if I want to Predict posterior probability of data per each component.

However, I cannot find a similar method in 'tensorflow gmm_ops'

Did anyone find that before?